# Carnot's engine duration

Tags: thermodynamics

Can I get work forever with out burning fuel from the Carnot's engine?
I know that Carnot's cycle is 100% efficient. It changes heat to work without wasting the heat. But does it work with out fuel for ever?

Comment: Uh, this seems to be a serious misunderstanding of what a Carnot engine does. Carnot engines do need to be 'fueled', with heat. They're as efficient as possible, but that doesn't mean 100% efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Carnot engine has an efficiency of
$$ \eta = 1 - \frac{T_c}{T_h} $$
where $T_c$ is the temperature of the cold reservoir and $T_h$ the temperature of the warm reservoir. The carnot engine is thus not running at 100% efficiency and due to Carnot's theorem (that there can be no heat engine between too reservoirs operating with higher efficiency) we know that 100% efficiency is not possible. (This is equivalent to the Kelvin-Planck statement which states that it is **impossible** to fully convert heat into mechanical work.)

Note that a carnot engine is a theoretical concept from equilibrium thermodynamics, time does not come into the equation here. Of course you can calculate how much heat energy it needs for a cycle and thus how much of your fuel you would need to burn, but that is a rather academic exercise. An engine running forever without fuel is however impossible - this would violate the first law of thermodynamics.